# Digit limitation from decimal point in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I have a double variable `double a=0.1239857` and I want to limit variable `a` from decimal point two digits. So `a` will be `0.12`. I know  C++ have functions that return largest or smallest integer that is greater or lower than `a` like ceil or floor.

Is there a function that implements digit limitation of floating-point variable? Or How can I change precision of the `a` variable?

Comment: Using std::fixed as shown in this answer would result in the required format
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout

Answer (score 25):

Are you actually trying to round the number, or just change its displayed precision?

For the former (truncating the extra digits):

```
double scale = 0.01;  // i.e. round to nearest one-hundreth
value = (int)(value / scale) * scale;
```

or (rounding up/down as appropriate, per jheriko's answer)

```
double scale = 0.01;  // i.e. round to nearest one-hundreth
value = floor(value / scale + 0.5) * scale;
```

For the latter:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << value;
```

where the parameter to `setprecision()` is the maximum number of digits to show after the decimal point.

Comment: Note that when you use setprecision on a stream like you show, it will round also.

Comment: Brian - please elaborate.  Sure, it'll _show_ the value rounded up or down to the appropriate number of places, but it won't change the value actually stored in the variable.

Comment: The value will be rounded to the appropriate precision upon display to cout. Of course it has no effect on the value in the variable.

Comment: I was trying to say it does both: setprecision shows the value to the desired precision, *and* rounds while doing so.

Comment: You need to use "fixed" as well. `cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << value;`

Answer (score 9):

This will result in two digits after the decimal place.

```
a = floor(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

Comment: Although not asked by OP: Note that when printing `a` it is not guaranteed to show only 2 digits. It will have rounding errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to output the value, you can do something like

```
printf("%.3f", a); // Output value with 3 digits after comma
```

If you want to convert the value itself, you can do:

```
a = (int)(a * 1000) / 1000.0f;
```

Note that both do no rounding, they just truncate the value.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by you want to limit the variable ? The value or its formatting. For the value, you can use floor + division. Something like:

```
double a = 0.12123
double b;

b = floor(a * 100) / 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ios_base::precision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/) for formatting i/o.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the precision on a stream, e.g.

```
double d = 3.14579;
cout.precision(2);
cout << d << endl;

// Or use a manipulator

#include <iomanip>
cout << setprecision(2) << d << endl;
```

Note that when you send a double or float to a stream like this, it will automatically round for you (which can trip you up sometimes if you aren't aware of this).

Answer (score 1):

An actual rounding solution would be `x = floor(100*x + 0.5) / 100;` assuming the value to be rounded is in a variable "x".

The `x = floor(100*x) / 100;` recommended by others here will actually truncate the number to 2dp instead.

Comment: i could not understand linefloor(100*x + 0.5) / 100

Answer (score 1):

you could also do something like this:

```
//This code will ask the user for an input, set the decimal precision to the hundredths place,  and add 4.63 to the inputted variable

int banana;
cin >> banana;
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << banana + 4.63;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function as follows, it can handle rounding errors for decimals as well.

```
double RoundForGivenPrecision(const double dNumber, int iDecimalPlaces)
{
long long multiplier = (long long)pow(10, iDecimalPlaces);
long double value = dNumber < 0 ? (long long)((nextafter(dNumber, -DBL_MAX)*multiplier)-0.5) : (long long)((nextafter(dNumber,DBL_MAX)*multiplier)+0.5);
return value / multiplier;
}
```