# Printing the correct number of decimal places with cout

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, iostream

I have a list of `float` values and I want to print them with `cout` with 2 decimal places.

For example:

- 10.900  should be printed as 10.90
- 1.000 should be printed as 1.00
- 122.345 should be printed as 122.34

How can I do this?

(`setprecision` doesn't seem to help in this.)

Answer (score 324, accepted):

With `<iomanip>`, you can use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double d = 122.345;

    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << d;
}
```

And you will get output

```
122.34
```

Comment: why do you used "std:fixed" in program?

Comment: A useful header can be defined for this: `#define FIXED_FLOAT(x) std::fixed <<std::setprecision(2)<<(x) ` which simplifies the usage to: `cout<<FIXED_FLOAT(d)`

Comment: @VilasJoshi, setprecision set the number of digits after the decimal, if there are 5 digits and we use setprecision(2) we will get 2 digits , but if there are 0 digits it will show none, using fixed we fix that much digits have to be shown so 5 will be represented as 5.00 no 5

Comment: @vaibnak That's misleading to the point of wrong. `setprecision` sets "the number of digits", which depending on the state that `std::fixed` sets is either "significant digits", "digits after the decimal place" or "digits after the *hexadecimal* place"

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Caleth. Note for other people that "n place after decimal point" is indeed using setprecision in fixed

Comment: Doesn't work for negative numbers, like -0.4 with a precision of 2

Answer (score 60):

You were nearly there, need to use std::fixed as well, refer http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float testme[] = { 0.12345, 1.2345, 12.345, 123.45, 1234.5, 12345 };

    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << testme[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
0.12
1.23
12.35
123.45
1234.50
12345.00
```

Answer (score 22):

`setprecision(n)` applies to the entire number, not the fractional part.  You need to use the fixed-point format to make it apply to the fractional part: `setiosflags(ios::fixed)`

Answer (score 19):

Simplify the accepted answer

Simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double d = 122.345;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << d;
}
```

And you will get output

```
122.34
```

Reference:

- [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)
- [`std::setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

Comment: This worked for me:
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << d;

Answer (score 9):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{

 double d=15.6464545347;

printf("%0.2lf",d);

}
```

Comment: what is the significance of the `l` format specifier?

Answer (score 7):

I had this similar problem in a coding competition and this is how I handled it.
Setting a precision of 2 to all double values

First adding the header to use setprecision

`#include <iomanip>`

Then adding the following code in our main

```
  double answer=5.9999;
  double answer2=5.0000;
  cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed;
  cout <<answer << endl;
  cout <<answer2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
5.99
5.00
```

You need to use fixed for writing 5.00 thats why,your output won't come for 5.00.

[A short reference video link I'm adding which is helpful](https://youtu.be/d_OMH61be5g)

Answer (score 3):

To set fixed 2 digits after the decimal point use these first:

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);
```

Then print your double values.

This is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::ios;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    double d = 10.90;
    cout << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    long int b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
    cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<c<<"\n";
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3)<<d<<"\n";
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(9)<<e;
    return 0;
}
```

**Simple code would help you surely!**

Answer (score 2):

with templates

```
#include <iostream>

// d = decimal places
template<int d> 
std::ostream& fixed(std::ostream& os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    return os; 
}

int main(){
    double d = 122.345;
    std::cout << fixed<2> << d;
}
```

similar for scientific as well, with a width option also (useful for columns)

```
// d = decimal places
template<int d> 
std::ostream& f(std::ostream &os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    return os; 
}

// w = width, d = decimal places
template<int w, int d> 
std::ostream& f(std::ostream &os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    os.width(w);
    return os; 
}

// d = decimal places
template<int d> 
std::ostream& e(std::ostream &os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    return os; 
}

// w = width, d = decimal places
template<int w, int d> 
std::ostream& e(std::ostream &os){
    os.setf(std::ios_base::scientific, std::ios_base::floatfield); 
    os.precision(d); 
    os.width(w);
    return os; 
}

int main(){
    double d = 122.345;
    std::cout << f<10,2> << d << '\n'
        << e<10,2> << d << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the 'float mode' to fixed.

```
float num = 15.839;

// this will output 15.84
std::cout << std::fixed << "num = " << std::setprecision(2) << num << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you can use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
std::cout << std::format("{:.2f}", 10.900);
```

Output:

```
10.90
```

It is less verbose and more efficient than using I/O manipulators. It also gives you control over locale with the default being locale-independent.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() {
double d = 122.345;
printf(".2%lf",d); 
}
```

Comment: This answer is basically the same answer as the one by saurav52, does not use `cout` as per OPs question, and includes a typo in the format string.

Answer (score -4):

Just a minor point; put the following in the header

using namespace std;

then

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << d;

becomes simplified to

cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << d;

Answer (score -6):

this an example using a matrix.

```
cout<<setprecision(4)<<fixed<<m[i][j]
```