# How can I pad a float with leading zeros when using cout << operator

Tags: c++, cout

Putting together these questions:

[How can I pad an int with leading zeros when using cout << operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714515/2436175)

[Printing the correct number of decimal points with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout)

How can I stream to std::cout, for example, this variable

```
double x = 7.1224
```

And make it look like this?

```
07.12
```

Comment: The mystery of the downvote...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Combine [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw), [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill), [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision):

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) 
          << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << x;
```

So, the value for setw is: 2 for the precision desired + 2 for the integer desired + 1 for the floating point.

Note: `x = 107.1224` will be outputted as `107.12`.