# How to use setprecision in cpp for only the number of floating points

Tags: c++, precision, cout, iomanip

When cout-ing a number with floating points, i.e. 31.14159, how can I set cout to use the setprecision(4) on the floating point:

```
cout <<setprecision(4)<< 31.14159<<endl; // returns 31.14
```

As-is, it considers the whole number with its decimal digits, and outputs: 31.14. However, I want to get: 31.1416.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing the correct number of decimal points with cout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::fixed says that there will be a fixed number of decimal digits after the decimal point.

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << std::fixed << 31.14159;
```

- this will print `31.1416`

Comment: I was trying to understand 'setprecision' by adding 2 doubles, the addition had '0' in the decimal part. and the answer printed using 'cout<<setprecision(2)' without adding 'std::fixed' resulted in not printing of decimal part of the answer... Can you explain, why this happened

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << 31.14159 << endl ;
```

and you will get output as `31.1416`

When you add `std::fixed`, the `std::setprecision(4)` will take effect on the decimal part, and thus you will get `4` values after the decimal point.

A `std::setprecision()` will take effect on the entire number. But when you add a `std::fixed` along with it, the `std::setprecision()` will effect only the decimal part of the number.

Comment: I was trying to understand 'setprecision' by adding 2 doubles, the addition had '0' in the decimal part. and the answer printed using 'cout<<setprecision(2)' without adding 'std::fixed' resulted in not printing of decimal part of the answer... Can you explain, why this happened