# C++ The compiler converts from double to int

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple class in c++ simulating card payments and doing simple arithmetic operations and the compiler converts my double variable to int. In my class I have a `makePayment` method which returns `double` and it is working fine. The problem comes when I try to `charge` my card and somehow it appears like the `balance` variable in the class changes from `double` to `int`, because after I `charge` my card every operation or when I print the `balance` it returns an integer.

```
class DebitCard {

public:

   DebitCard();

   bool makePayment(double amount);

   const double& getBalance() 
      { return balance; }

   void dailyInterest()
      { balance *= interest; }

   void chargeCard(double amount)
      { balance += amount; }

private:

   string card_number;
   short pin;
   double balance;
   double payment_fee;    // percentage fee for paying with the card
   double interest;       // daily interest
   //double charge_tax;     // percentage taxing for charing the card

};
```

and here are the tests I do in the main function

```
   DebitCard d;   // balance is set to 100   

   d.makePayment(91.50);
   cout << std::setprecision(3) << d.getBalance() << endl;    // 7.58

   d.chargeCard(200);
   cout << std::setprecision(3) << d.getBalance() << endl;  // 208

   d.makePayment(91.50);
   cout << std::setprecision(3) << d.getBalance() << endl;    // 115
```

I really can't wrap my head around why is that happening, so if someone could explain me, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [std::showpoint, std::noshowpoint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision : "Manages the precision (i.e. ***how many digits are generated***) of floating point output ..."

Comment: bool makePayment(double amount);  ?? implementation?

Comment: If you had run this in a debugger you would have seen that the `balance` member is maintained correctly. Then you would have been closer to discovering your precision mistake.

Comment: I didn't even suppose that it could've been from the setprecision(). Thank you all :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout explains the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`set::precision(3)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) is asking for 3 digits in the output.

And that's what you get.

Comment: Got it, a std::fixed fixed it :) Thank you for the fast reply!