# Different rounding results in terms of floating number ending with 5 in C++

Tags: c++, rounding

I was looking for a method to round float numbers in c++ this morning and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout) solve my problem.

However, I notice something unusual to me. When I try to round certain float numbers to two decimal places, it seems like numbers such as 1.075 and 1.895 follow different rounding rules. Specifically, with the following simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float testme[] = { 1.07500, 1.89500, 2.70500, 3.47500};
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
       std::cout << testme[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I have is

```
1.08
1.89
2.70
3.47
```

So 1.075 turns to 1.08 while 1.895 becomes 1.89. This really confused me. I would appreciate some explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Print more characters and get a better look at how 1.075 and 1.895 are really being represented: https://ideone.com/y52ZLJ

Comment: Those numbers probably can't be represented exactly in binary, so you never have these numbers. Rounding is then influenced accordingly.

Comment: You are not rounding the numbers. The `std::setprecision(2)` does not round anything. You should be using type `double` instead of `float` and `std::round` or similar if you want to round the number.

Comment: Strongly related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Sadly upping the size to `double` is not good enough: https://ideone.com/EzKDWY And again with more digits: https://ideone.com/oOpmGe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with floating-point numbers not being able to precisely represent the number 1.895. The closest floating point value to 1.895 that the computer can store is actually

```
1.894999980926513671875
```

which, if rounded to two decimal places, actually *should be* 1.89, since after looking at the next digit you'd round down.

I managed to get the above number using [this tool](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), which might also come in handy for explaining other values.

Answer (score 0):

Most decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary format, so they have to be rounded. IEEE 754 defines several possibilities for this procedure, I think you see this one (citation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules)):

> Round to nearest, ties to even – rounds to the nearest value; if the number falls midway it is rounded to the nearest value with an even (zero) least significant bit; this is the default for binary floating-point and the recommended default for decimal.

Basically, decimal numbers which end with digit 5 are sometimes rounded up and sometimes rounded down to avoid a statistical drift.