# My double is rounding up the decimals and I don't want it to

Tags: c++, type-conversion, decimal

I converted a string to a double using ::atof, it converts OK but it rounds up the decimal and I don't want it to.

```
string n;
double p;

cout << "String? :" << endl;
cin >> n

p = ::atof(n.c_str());
cout << p << endl;
```

I usually type in numbers like 123,456.78, 12,345.87, 123,456,789.12. When I type in a smaller number like 1,234.83 or bigger the programs starts messing with the decimals.

It would be of huge help if anybody helps. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `cin >> p`?

Comment: [Extend the displayed precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: @NeilButterworth why do you say so? Is there a easier way to convert a string into a double?

Comment: [strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) and [std::stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). Both allow you to catch a number of failure cases that `atof` merely "reports" by returning 0.0.

Comment: Near miss duplicate: [Printing the correct number of decimal points with cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout)

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nQLEN529EJm1Ku2S ?

Comment: Both C and C++ provide a number of ways of converting a string to a double - atof is the only one that does not provide a means of checking if the conversion actually worked.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, and how would I use those in this case?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Oh okay, and what do you recommend that I should be using to check if the conversion worked?

Comment: @javiersantisteban My answer shows you how to use `stod` and `setprecision`. You should be able to cobble together working code from all the comments and answer(s) now.

Comment: `p = std::stod(n);` is about as easy as it gets, assuming your compiler supports C++11 (at this point it sure as <expletive deleted> should) and C++11 support is enabled (g++ option `-std=c++11`). If `stod` can't convert, an exception is thrown. You can check if there is crap left over in the string by providing the optional `pos` parameter and making sure that it's at the end of the string.

Comment: If you have to use an older C++ standard or bad inputs are't going to be exceptional enough to make using exceptions make sense, `strtod` has a good example at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof). It's too messy to go through in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the precision used when sending data to the output stream using `setprecision` as shown below.

Of course the problem with this code is that `atof()` isn't your best option. However, to answer your question the use of `atof()` doesn't matter.

```
#include <iomanip>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>

int main()
{
    double x;
    std::string n;

    std::cout << "String? :" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    x = ::atof(n.c_str());
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << x << std::endl;
}
```

To convert and catch conversion errors you could use the following:

```
try
{
    x = std::stod(n);
}
catch(std::invalid_argument)
{
    // can't convert
}
```