# Recursion not working inside a loop in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a problem to solve in C++ which is as follow : 1 + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + (1/4!) + (1/5!)... and so on

The code I have written for the same is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact(int);

int main()
{
    int n; float sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter number of terms:";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (float)(1/(fact(i)));
    }

    cout<<endl<<"The sum is :"<<sum;
    return 0;
}

int fact(int x)
{
    if(x == 0 || x == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * fact(x-1);
}
```

The above code is not returning any output. Earlier I have computed factorial without using for loop. And the recursion has worked.

Comment: The other reason that your program is 'not returning any output' (not even zero) is that it doesn't print anything. Add `cout << "the sum is " << sum << endl;`

Comment: I modified the code as above, still no success... :(

Comment: That was just a mistake, I changed the position of return statement, its the last one now, again no success...

Comment: Replace `if(x == 0 || x == 1)  return 0;` with `if( x == 0 || x == 1)
            return 1;` and `sum = sum + (float)(1.0/(fact(i)));`

Comment: I changed the same, getting answer as well, but not getting precise decimals even though the data type is float.

Comment: Change this : sum = sum + (float)(1/(fact(i))); to  sum = sum + 1/(float)fact(i);

Comment: All your `int`s should be unsigned types (probably `std::size_t` or `std::uint_fast16_t`). Think about `fact(-1)`.

Comment: @Stuti Unfortunately you'll get answers based on the code you post, not the code you have. People (not just you) are extraordinarilly bad at posting the code they are having trouble with. It only requires cut and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your base case in the recursion:

```
int fact(int x)
{
    if(x == 0 || x == 1)
        return 0;
...
```

which makes all factorials zero, and then you divide by zero: `1/(fact(i))` and crash your program.

The proper base case is `1`, and you need to avoid integer division with `1.0f/fact(i)`.

You would have spotted the base-case bug quickly if you had tested the `fact` function on its own first.

Comment: Oh!! This was a big logical error, thanks for pointing out. I changed that return statement to return 1, and yet the answer I am getting is "1". I want it with precise decimals.

Comment: With these two fixes, your program produces 1.71806 for n = 6. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1edd57d602795ce5).

Answer (score 2):

The culprit here is **Integral Division** in C++.

If one of the operand is integer C++ performs integral division which by nature **discards fractional part**. If at least one of them is float or double the result is kept. For example check output for following statements.

```
cout<<(1/5);   // Gives 0 Umm.. weird
```

```
cout<<(1/5.0); // Gives 0.2 Umm.. works
```

```
cout<<(1.0/5)  // Gives 0.2 Umm.. also works
```

Now in your code, modify:

```
sum = sum + 1/fact(i);
```

to

```
sum = sum + 1/(1.f*fact(i));
```

or **typecast explicitly at least one of operand**.

```
sum += 1/(float)(fact(i));
```

Also note that:

```
(float)(1/5)
```

will not work as the typecasting occurs after integral division so make sure at least one of operand is float or double before division.

You can read more on how integral divison works in C++.

Full working code for your reference :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  //for precision
using namespace std;

int fact(int x){
    if(x == 0 || x == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return x * fact(x-1);
}

int main(){
    int n; 
    float sum=0;

    //to set precision upto 3 decimal places
    cout << std::fixed;
    cout << std::setprecision(3);

    cout<<"Enter number of terms: ";
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        sum = sum + 1/(1.f*fact(i));
        //sum += 1/(float)(fact(i));  or use typecasting like this
    }

    cout<<"The sum is :"<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To know more about setting precision check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout).

Comment: How is the division related to the lack of output?

Comment: As I have mentioned in note using typecasting after integral division will not work. Please use before division happens. Check commented code for same.

Comment: You should use `static_cast<float>(x)` instead of `1.0*x` for casting to `float`. Especially given that the literal `1.0` is of type `double`.

Comment: Or simply `1.f/fact(i)`. Like in the third coce example, just with a float literal.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM

The problem here is the lack of proper type casting in widening primitive conversions. Any operation between 2 int operators will produce an int, and casting the whole expression will result in loss of value. 
In this case, the "sum = sum + 1/fact(i);" line has two problems. fact(i) being an int value, 1/fact(i) will return an int (read 0, for i>1) and then the variable sum is an int, so even if 1/fact(i) returns a double value, sum will just be able to hold the implicitly cast int value.
Kindly refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/type-conversions-and-type-safety-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019

SOLUTION

Multiple solutions are possible for this.

1. The easiest - you could just declare sum to be a double and change the line inside the loop to - sum = sum + 1.0/fact(i);
2. Or, you could declare sum to be a double and typecast or declare the return type of fact(i) to be a double.

And just to add lest I forget, I suppose you'll actually return or print the final sum value to check this code.

Hope this is helpful and clear!

Answer (score 0):

*I corrected code snnipet*.
1.) You had return 0; in main before printing sum.

2.)In factorial function you have return 0 which will give infinity when divided by any number. It will cause exception.
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int fact(int);

int main()
 {
  int n; float sum=0;
  cout<<"Enter number of terms:";
  cin>>n;

  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    sum = sum + (float)(1.0/(fact(i)));
  }
  cout<<"The sum is :"<<sum<<endl;

  return 0;
  }

 int fact(int x)
 {
    if(x == 0 || x == 1)
       return 1;
    else
       return x * fact(x-1);
 }
```

Comment: I corrected this thing and the answer returned is 1. Exactly "1" What if I need it with trailing decimals, and it should give decimals instead of "1" because the datatype is float.

Comment: return 1.0 instead of 1

Comment: I think you have edited your question with fix, so now your question should not even exist.

Comment: I edited the question with fix, right, but I am still  getting integer 1 as the answer. No trailing decimals... :( any solution to that ? Or maybe I should start a separate thread on the same ?

Comment: I executed it is showing precise value in sum. upto 6 decimal place. if you want more you can use double

Comment: I am getting correct answer in double, but not in float ... :( Maybe compiler difference? I am using GCC GNU compiler with codeblocks...

Comment: you mean you are not getting answer in decimal form? you only getting integer?

Comment: you need to explicitly typecast by writing 1 as 1.0 in sum = sum + (float)(1.0/(fact(i)));

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid recomputing the factorial if you keep a running term inside your loop:

```
inline float inv_fseries(std::size_t lim) {
  float term = 1.f;
  float sum = 1.f;
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= lim; ++i) {
     term /= static_cast<float>(i);
     sum += term;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The `static_cast` can also be avoided by using a `float` running variable, but care must be given to avoid floating-point related off-by-one errors (not every integer can be represented by a `float`)

```
inline float inv_fseries(std::size_t lim) {
  float term = 1.f;
  float sum = 1.f;
  float const bound = static_cast<float>(lim) + 0.5f;
  for (float i = 1.f; i <= bound; ++i) {
     term /= i;
     sum += term;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

One could argue that this has worse runtime because we replaced integer point operations with floating point operations. But at the point where this becomes an issue your limit n is so large that the whopping O(n^2) in the original algorithm versus this algorithm's O(n) outweighs all overhead from floating-point multiplications.

On a related note: **never** plug user-provided numbers into recursive functions if the recursion depth depends on those numbers. Literally the name of this website. ;)