# Algorithm for the cube root Find in C++

Tags: c++

Iam Beginner in programming and i have a question.
how make algorithm for cube root finding in C++ without using functions like pow().
The user enters the number and the number of decimal places.

My code:
My do while isn't working

```
double number;
cout << "Enter number = ";
cin >> number;
int x;
int y = number / 3.;
int i;
cout << "Enter i = ";
cin >> i;
do {
    x = y;
    y = (2. * x + number / (x * x)) / 3.;
} while (abs(x - y) >= i);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ? Do you know the forumla and have problems to write the code for it or are you also looking for the right formula?

Comment: First, shouldn't all your variables be of type `double`, or at the very least, a floating point type?

Comment: Without mathematical formula, binary_search between `1` and `x` until `upper - lower < 10**-i`?

Comment: You need to be more specific of what you want.
Are you just interested in integer solutions to x^3 = y?
Do you want a good floating point approximation?
Do you want an approximation with exact error bounds?

Comment: The easy way is to cheat:  search the internet for "c++ find cube root".  In modern times, search the internet first, there is usually an existing algorithm or example residing on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is *nearly* fine. You just need to change your variables to `float`/`double`. Here is the edited code :

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double number;
    cout << "Enter number = ";
    cin >> number;
    double x;
    double y = number / 3.;
    double i;
    cout << "Enter i = ";
    cin >> i;
    do {
        x = y;
        y = (2. * x + number / (x * x)) / 3.;
    } while (abs(x - y) >= numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
    cout << fixed << setprecision(i) << y;
}
```

[**Sample Run :**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/32tV6pdlSYm8qFEK)

```
Enter number = 10
Enter i = 2
2.15
```

A little add up :

As pointed out by [chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica), `abs(x - y) >= numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` is not a good condition to check equality. You can go through this thread for more knowledge : [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Another one : [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: But how to implement in the code so that the user himself indicates how many characters should be displayed after the point?

Comment: it's like number = 5; i = 2;          output : 5.11

Comment: [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to limit display.

Comment: @Fred As Jarod42 mentioned, [use `std::fixed` followed by `std::setprecision`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout). [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/32tV6pdlSYm8qFEK) is an example usage. Reflected the edit in the answer. :)

Comment: @Fred How can the output be `5.11`?? For `5 2` as input, shouldn't the output be `1.71`?

Comment: `abs(x - y) >= numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` is a poor terminating condition for very large and very small `x`.  That takes the float out of floating point.