# How to correctly store the result of arithmetic operations on int type to double type and different types in C++?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I have two times stored in `int` type in a `struct` and want to calculate the no. of hours elapsed in between two times. How do I correctly store the result of in a `double` variable. I seem to get the difference wrong. Also how do I store the result up to two places after the decimal point.
This is my code :

```
struct time
{
int hour=0,min=0;
char am_pm='a';
};

int main()
{
time t1,t2; 
// GET THE TIME INPUT FROM THE USER HERE
//assuming always t2's hour and min are always numerically greater than t1's hour and min and always `am`

double hour_diff=0.00,min_diff=0.00;
double time_elapsed=0.00;
cout<<"The time elapsed between your entered times is : ";

hour_diff=t2.hour-t1.hour; counting hour difference
min_diff=(t2.min+t1.min)/60; //counting total minutes and converting them into hours

time_elapsed=hour_diff+min_diff;
cout<<time_elapsed;
```

if i give these input i get wrong result 7 when i should get 7.25 :

```
INPUT
t1.hour = 5
t1.min = 30
t1.am_pm = a;

t2.hour = 11
t2.min = 45
t2.am_pm = a;

time elapsed = 7 // this is wrong, I should be getting 7.25
```

Comment: Try `min_diff=(t2.min+t1.min)/60.0;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao is right. All sub-expressions (the variables and the literal) of `(t2.min+t1.min)/60` are ints, so the expression is an int, too. Just like in `int i = 5/3;` i is 1 (i.e., `(double(i) == 1.0` holds), the value of the expression is just the integer fraction. If you change one of the operands to float or double, operands in operations with it (here: `(t2.min+t1.min)` will be converted to float or double as well, and the resulting expression will be float or double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because this expression `(t2.min+t1.min)/60` will return `int`.

That's because `(t2.min+t1.min)` is of type `int` and `60` is of type `int`. Hence `\` will be an integer division operation.

To resolve it you can convert your `(t2.min+t1.min)` to the `double` with `static_cast<double>(t2.min+t1.min)`. See more about [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Or you can simply define `60` as a double by writing `60.0`.

Comment: Can you also explain how to get only two points after the decimal point?

Comment: Can you also explain how to get only two points after the decimal point?\

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma if you need to print to output only 2 decimal points, then you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout
If you want to store only 2 decimal points. Then you can multiply your number by 100, `floor`, `ceil` or `round` it and then divide by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are performing integer operations '(t2.min + t1.min)/60', even though you are storing them in a variable of type double, become simplified to an integer type.
Either make 60 a double by changing it to '60.0' or encompass the whole result with a 'static_cast' before your operations.

Comment: What do you think `static_cast<double>(4/3)` will be?