# About print out decimal numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem. The task is to calculate
`x = pow (a, 5) - 2*sqrt (abs (b)) + a * b * c`
and print out the result with to number behind the decimal point. I googled and found out the use of `iomanip` library and `setprecision()` function, and it worked. But I don't know why when the input is -10, -20, -30, it printed out -106008.95 while it should be -106008.94

Please help me to fix this, thank you so much

Comment: what's `grpc-c++` and how does it relate to this?

Answer (score -1):

The actual output with 9 decimal point precision is -106008.945 so, when you are setting precision to 8 it just omit the 9th decimal point and as this value '5' (9th decimal point) is in the range of [ 5 to 9 ] they are just adding '1' to 8th decimal point value.

So, -106008.945 becomes -106008.95 when it comes to 8 decimal point precision.

If you want -106008.945 to become -106008.94 when you set the decimal point to 8, you can checkout this [stackoverflow link where exactly this case was discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907031/printing-the-correct-number-of-decimal-points-with-cout)

Comment: this is funny that, trying to help out newbies results in negative behaviour in stackoverflow now a days. The guy is super newbie to ask that ques and it also took me some time to get what he even asking. I tried my best to satisfy his ans but here it goes..!