# set decimal numbers according to parameter

Tags: c++, math

Is there a direct function to set the decimal of number. For example I got `3.14341`
and my parameter is `2`, so I get `3.14`. There is a function `setprecision` but it only prints the result. Also, I made an algorithm like this:

```
std::string fixPrecision(std::string const& value, int digits)
{
    std::string num = value;
    float temp = std::stof(num);
    float  fractpart, intpart;
    fractpart = modf(temp, &intpart);
    int a = (int)(fractpart * pow(10,digits));
    double last = intpart + a*(pow(0.1 , digits));
    return std::to_string(last);
}
```

It works well. I get what I want but I have to convert it to string so the result is `123.120000` instead of `123.12`.

I could sure use some help here. Thanks in advance.

Edit: It is not a duplicate question because my function needs to take integer and return numbers with string format. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you want to round the number internally.  Normally you only need to round it when you display it.  Normally there is not a need to get rid of precision.  If you are working with something like currency then you should be using integers/a fixed precision library.

Comment: This is my task in company and numbers should be sent with strings thanks for the answer

Comment: This can be achieved with a `std::stringstream` and manipulators such as `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision`. However, you might want to consider manipulating the string directly. Using an intermediate `float` risks damaging your precision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digit limitation from decimal point in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798046/digit-limitation-from-decimal-point-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fool of me. The answer is as simple as this. I did a lot of things needlessly...

```
 std::string fixPrecision(std::string const& value, int digits)
 {
     auto pos = value.find(".");
     if(pos != std::string::npos)
     return value.substr(0, pos+digits+1);
     return value;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

not exactly, but you can set the precision using **std::setprecision**

define a method:

```
void printWithPrecision(const double value, unsigned decimalPlaces)
{
    std::cout << "A Double with " << decimalPlaces <<" decimal places: "<<std::setprecision(decimalPlaces) << value << std::endl;
}
```

and call it like:

```
double d = 7987.12354689765416;

for (auto x = 0; x<10; x++)
{
    printWithPrecision(d, x);
}
```

dont forget to include the input-output-manipulator:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i dont want to print it instead i want to assign it.

Comment: but that is a double, you just can not modify the 53 bits defining it (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008 )

Comment: may be there is a string function(after i convert to string) for this...